# C program crashes because of pointer assignment

Tags: c, ansi-c

I'm writing a program for one of the exercises in the ANSI C book, and the program crashes when I reach this line:

```
*pmonth = i;
```

in function month_day.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void month_day(int year, int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int year = 1994;
    int *month;
    int yearday = 288;
    int *day;
    month_day(year, yearday, month, day);
    printf("Month = %d, day = %d", *month, *day);
    return 1;
}

static char daytab[2][14] = {
        {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
        {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
};

void month_day(int year, int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday){
    int i, leap;

    leap = (year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0) || year%400 == 0;
    char *p = &daytab[leap][1];
    for(i = 1; yearday> (int) *p; i++){
        yearday -= *p++;
    }
    *pmonth = i; /*CRASHES HERE*/
    *pday = yearday;
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm relatively new to pointers, so i could easily be making a stupid mistake. Thanks in advance.

*EDIT* Thank you guys for your answers and patience, trying to get the hang of pointers.

Comment: `int month, day;`.. `month_day(year, yearday, &month, &day);`

Comment: `*pmonth = i` is **not** a pointer assignment.

Comment: Most compilers should issue warnings for the code in question, some by default. gcc and clang need for example `-Wall` option. Then the question would hopefully be about what to do about `warning: 'month' is used uninitialized in this function` warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer `pmonth` is not initialized. So you **should not dereference it**. You should assign a valid address to your pointer. To do this you can either assign a variable address with the `&` operator or call `malloc(1)`.

Since you don't seems to need pointers in your main function, your code should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int year = 1994;
    int month;
    int yearday = 288;
    int day;
    month_day(year, yearday, &month, &day);
    printf("Month = %d, day = %d", month, day);
    return 1;
}
```

In this code, we give to `pmonth` and `pday` the addresses of variables `month` and `day`. These variables exist in this context so their addresses are valid. This way, `pmonth` and `pday` points to valid memory.

If you really need pointers in your main function, call `malloc(1)` to allocate memory to your program and store the address of this memory chunk into your pointer.

Comment: Nice answer, Plus 1.

Comment: I see, thank you. The problem really is my unfamiliarity with pointers.

Comment: @Slavvio: you're welcome :). In my opinion pointers is the hardest concept to understand. It will be easier with more practice ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you never create any memory for `pmonth` to point to. You need to point any pointer at some memory for it to edit, if you  do not and the pointer is uninitialized or `NULL` then you have **Undefined Behavior**. Undefined behaviour means anything could happen, including the program crashing or stealing your car.

Something like this would suffice:

```
int month; // Some actual memory.
int *pmonth = &month; // pmonth now points to something real.
```

But then again, the point of the `month_day` function is to provide output parameters, so even this would suffice:

```
int month, day;

month_day( ..., &month, &day)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Never use an uninitialized pointer or dereference a null pointer**, what you have done is undefined behaviour, anything in the world could happen.

You have defined a function `void month_day(int year, int yearday, int *pmonth, int *pday)` which requires two pointers to int (`pmonth and pday`) to be passed to it. You have passed pointer to int correctly and compiler has compiled your program successfully but these pointers doesn't point to correct memory addresses. When you access the address being pointed by your un-initialized pointer (which may be invalid or doesn't belong to you), you get `Segmentation Fault`.

Segmentation fault is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that “does not belong to you.” It’s a helper mechanism that keeps you from corrupting the memory and introducing hard-to-debug memory bugs.

There are many ways to get a segfault. A common way to get a segfault is to dereference a null pointer:

```
int *p = NULL;
*p = 1;
```

To solve your problem, your code should be like the one given below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int year = 1994;
    int month;
    int yearday = 288;
    int day;

    month_day(year, yearday, &month, &day);
    printf("Month = %d, day = %d", month, day);

    return 0;
}
```

Or

You can call `malloc` function to allocate memory dynamically and assign address returned by `malloc` function to your pointer variables. `Remember, to call free function to release memory allocated dynamically when you no longer need the memory`.